# Undo "Never for this site" in Mitro

Tags: password-management, mitro

I've installed the [Mitro Login Manager](https://www.mitro.co/) plugin to Firefox. When logging into any site there's an option to <kbd>Save</kbd> the login details or <kbd>Never for this site</kbd>.

If I've clicked the "Never" option but later want to save those details, how can I undo or tell Mitro to save the details after all? Is there any way to reset the list of "Never" sites?

[image: Mitro Save / Never]